# What do I need to put at the top of my HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have the following at the top of my document:

```
<html class="js" lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Can someone tell me if I need the xmlns part? I am not 100% sure but I think this is 
doing some things to my tags. For example when I look at the  tag is see the
following with firebug:

```
element.style {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If I just have this as at the top of my code then I don't see the element.style ..

```
<html class="js" lang="en">
```

Just to give some background. I'm developing an MVC application for use with English. It uses HTML5 things in a few places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current html spec, (which is html5) you will not need any fancy attributes, the following is adequate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Html page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is an example Html page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if you are not using the html5 spec, you should.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML5, then the extra tags probably should not be there as they are not needed any longer.. HTML5 uses a much cleaner syntax. :)

[Here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#a-basic-document) is the W3 documentation about this

Comment: The "you do not need it" should be a "it should not be there." The `xmlns` and `xml:lang` attributes are not valid attributes in HTML5.

Comment: By “extra tags” you apparently mean extra attributes. But according to the W3C HTML5 draft (all of HTML5 is work in progress only), “The syntax for using HTML with XML, whether in XHTML documents or embedded in other XML documents, is defined in the XML and Namespaces in XML specifications”. which means that `xml:lang` and `xmlns` are allowed. Ref.: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-xhtml-syntaxx

Comment: @Jukka: `xml:lang` is definitely no longer valid, it was replaced with just `lang`. I thought `xmlns` was replace with a broader `namespace` but apparently it does still exists, the only valid value being `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`.

Comment: @animuson, please check the reference I gave, and if desired use http://validator.nu/ (it’s very simple when using “Text Field” option—just cut and past the tag being discussed, to replace the plain `<html>` tag in the template). The `xml:lang` attribute is allowed, it has just been defined in a tricky way, see the HTML5 draft section on `lang`: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#attr-lang

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to give those attributes in the  tag.

```
<html>
</html>
```

will work fine even in HTML5 or HTML 4.01

Answer (score 0):

The `xmlns` attribute may be needed if the document will be processed by XML tools that do not necessarily use HTML namespace as the default. You can see this by saving the document locally and opening it in Firefox; if the `xmlns` attribute is missing, Firefox will display the document *source*, just with XML syntax coloring, because it treats all tags just as pure markup with do meaning or default rendering rules.

If the document is served as HTML (`Content-Type: text/html`), then browsers will imply HTML semantics (HTML namespace).

Regarding the question you asked in the heading, you should put a doctype declaration, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`, for all new documents. Otherwise you will trigger Quirks Mode, which means a large and undocumented set of oddities.